# Cisco IOS Tcl - Overhead

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, network

I've not been able to find much in regards to TCL other than the Cisco PDF "Cisco IOS Scripting with TCL Configuration Guide" and I just have a few queries.

I'm looking into potentially utilising this for pinging a range of addresses withing a specific range of DHCP to check for live hosts. (though this can be done via the broadcast address for our large sites it would produce un-neccessary output as well as ip directed-broadcast)

what I want to know, is if I enter TCLSH to write up a quick script to test the range I like, what effect does this have on the router - I.E

Does it create a script file in memory that is held or is it run and forgotten after i exit tcl mode?

Does the script cause any significant overhead on the router that is worth noting?

Less important, but something I've been trying to find - Is there any specific version that tcl was introduced to IOS as standard?

Cheers guys - appreciate anything that can be provided :)

Comment: Does it create a script file in memory that is held or is it run and forgotten after i exit tcl mode? Yes it's only saved temporary in memory. You can save the script to a normal text file and rename it to .tcl, then upload it to the falsh and run it from there, for instance: `Router#tclsh flash:/test.tcl`. The overhead is only significant if the script is extremely large and utilizes lots of different processes.

Comment: Hey @Cown ~

Thanks for the response, thats perfect, exactly what I was hoping - Had trouble finding the info in the cisco doc - looking through it atm, but theres alot thats going straight over my head!

Appreciate it!

Edit: appreciation

Comment: Cisco TCL scripting was introduced with versions: 12.3(2)T 12.3(7)T 12.2(25)S 12.2(33)SXH 12.2(33)SRC 12.2(33)SB Cisco IOS XE 3.1.0SG

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does it create a script file in memory that is held or is it run and
>   forgotten after I exit tcl mode?

Yes it's only saved temporary in memory. You can save the script to a normal text file and rename it to end with `.tcl`, then upload it to the flash and run it from there. For instance: `Router#tclsh flash:/test.tcl`.

> Does the script cause any significant overhead on the router that is
>   worth noting?

The overhead is only significant if the script is extremely large and utilizes lots of different processes. Remember that script errors with infinite loops can cause a switch to crash, even the high end versions.

> Less important, but something I've been trying to find - Is there any
>   specific version that tcl was introduced to IOS as standard?

**Cisco IOS Scripting with Tcl**

12.3(2)T 12.3(7)T 12.2(25)S 12.2(33)SXH 12.2(33)SRC 12.2(33)SB Cisco IOS XE 3.1.0SG

The Cisco IOS Scripting with Tcl feature provides the ability to run Tcl version 8.3.4 commands from the Cisco IOS command-line interface.

The following commands were introduced or modified: `scripting tcl encdir`, `scripting tcl init`, `scripting tcl low-memory`, `tclquit`, `tclsh`.

**Tcl SNMP MIB Access**

12.3(7)T 12.2(25)S 12.2(33)SXH 12.2(33)SRC 12.2(33)SB Cisco IOS XE 3.1.0SG

The Tcl SNMP MIB Access feature introduces a set of UNIX-like SNMP commands to make access to Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) MIB objects easier.

**Tcl UDP and VRF support**

15.1(1)T

The Tcl UDP and VRF feature provides support for UDP sockets in IOS Tcl.

The following commands were introduced or modified: `fconfigure`, `socket`, `udp_open`, `udp_peek`.

**Fun little script guide:**

http://www.ciscozine.com/ios-scripting-with-tcl/

**Example of large script:**

https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/eem-scripting/tcl-script-to-replace-text-in-a-file-stored-in-flash/td-p/2516640